# Unable to send large files using tcp socket from Java client to C++ server

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost-asio

I'm writing a C++ that has a feature of receiving file via socket from a Java client.
The file's size I'm trying to send is 510KB, but the server only receives 46KB and then gets stuck "waiting" for more bytes.

This is the server code: (I tried to receive 510KB at once, but the server got stuck, so I tried also to receive 64KB each iteration and again, the server got stuck).

```
int bytes_to_receive;
size_t length;
while(file_length > 0)
{
    if(file_length >= 65536)
        bytes_to_receive = 65536;
    else
        bytes_to_receive = file_length;
    char buf5[bytes_to_receive];
    length = 0;
    while( length < bytes_to_receive )
        length += socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&buf5[length], bytes_to_receive - length), error);

    string temp(buf5);
    file_parts.push_back(temp);
    file_length -= bytes_to_receive;
}

string file("");
vector<string>::const_iterator it;
for(it = file_parts.begin(); it != file_parts.end(); ++it)
{
    file += *it;
}
```

The Java client load the file to a string, and then sends the string using

```
writeBytes
```

Note: When sending a 1KB file everything works.

Why does this happens and how can I fix it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: any other way of receiving large data using boost would be appreciated.

Comment: If the reading code gets stuck the fault is probably in the sending code. Post it. NB you don't need to read entire files into memory just to send them.

Comment: And loading the file to a String and then sending the String using writeBytes() involves two character conversions which are liable to corrupt the data. String is not a container for binary data.